# Is InStr or my Wildcard Causing Problems?

Tags: vba, excel, text-parsing

I don't know why this doesn't work. It's part of a much larger subroutine, but I have narrowed the issue down to this use of a wildcard with the InStr function.

I have tried to find as much info on InStr and wildcards as I can, and as far as I can find this *should* work. But it doesn't.

```
    Dim String1 As String
    Dim String2 As String
    Dim TestString As String
    Dim Location As Integer

    String1 = "Hello"
    String2 = "Goodbye"
    TestString = "Hello and Goodbye"
    Location = InStr(1, TestString, (String1 & "*" & String2), vbTextCompare)
    If Location >= 1 then
        'Do Something
    End If
```

OK, I've tried some things based on what people have suggested, and now I'm at the point of this...

```
    Dim SourceString As String
    Dim TestString As String
    Dim TempArray() As String

    SourceString = "Hello and Goodbye"
    TestString = "hello * goodbye"

    TempArray = Split(TestString, "*")
    If SourceString Like _
          Chr(42) & TempArray(0) & Chr(42) & TempArray(1) & Chr(42) Then
       Found = True
    End If
```

I've done debug.print of each section of the TempArray and it includes the spaces, so I know it's splitting right.

What am I missing now? :(

Answer (score 5):

The [InStr function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8460tsh1.aspx) doesn't use pattern matching so your wildcard asterisk is being treated as a literal asterisk character (e.g. `Chr(42)`).

Perhaps switching to **Like** pattern matching would make a better boolean evaluation.

```
'method 1
If TestString Like Chr(42) & String1 & Chr(42) And _
   TestString Like Chr(42) & String2 & Chr(42) Then
    'Do Something
End If
'method 2
If TestString Like Chr(42) & String1 & Chr(42) & String2 & Chr(42) Then
    'Do Something
End If
```

Alternately, use a progression of InStr functions to ensure the correct matching order of String1 and String2.

```
'method 1
If CBool(InStr(1, TestString, String1, vbTextCompare)) And _
  InStr(1, TestString, String2, vbTextCompare) > InStr(1, TestString, String1, vbTextCompare) Then
    'Do Something
End If
'method 2
dim p as long
If CBool(InStr(1, TestString, String1, vbTextCompare)) Then
    p = InStr(1, TestString, String1, vbTextCompare) + Len(String1)
    If CBool(InStr(p, TestString, String2, vbTextCompare)) Then
        'Do Something
    End If
End If
```

Comment: Your `Instr` version may fail if `String2` occurs (before or within) and after `String1`

Comment: It will fail if String2 occurs before String1 but that is by design as it seemed to follow the `String1 & "*" & String2` pattern the OP was working toward originally. I hadn't thought of a false positive where String2 was a substring of String1 and not the first left-most characters. +1 Good catch! I'll edit in a correction. [edit] Seems like I came up with something closer to your own response.

Comment: if String2 is before _and_ after String1 it will give a false negative.  Your  original code will detect the first and return false, while the second should match the pattern.  (Revised version seems ok)

Comment: I looked at the Like function, but as I'm teaching myself VBA from the web (and in just a couple weeks), it only confused me more. In this case, I only need to know whether or not the test string is found, not where it is found in the source string. However, the order DOES matter.

Comment: The string I am testing for is actually stored in another worksheet in ThisWorkbook. The cell with the string I'm looking for would contain (for this example) "Hello*Goodbye" but some of the test strings contain spaces before or after the wildcard, some have 2 wildcards (effectively, there are 3 words that need to be in that order, but may have other words between them). There shouldn't be any situations where one section of the test cell is a substring of the other.

Comment: You can see from my revised [InStr](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8460tsh1.aspx) procedure (and [Chris' solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36993034/is-instr-or-my-wildcard-causing-problems/36994114#36994114))  that String2 is looked for at a position starting **after** String1. This seems to be what your original wildcarded 'mask' as looking for.

Comment: Jeeped, thank you for your answer and further comments. I definitely think the Like function (method 2) will be best for this situation, but I can't seem to make it work, either. :( I've edited my post with further information.

Answer (score 1):

The implied logic of `InStr(1, TestString, (String1 & "*" & String2), vbTextCompare)` is:

`TestString` contains `String1` followed by 0 or more characters, followed by `String2`

Since `Instr` does not support wildcards, break down the test into components

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim String1 As String
    Dim String2 As String
    Dim TestString As String
    Dim Location As Integer
    Dim i As Long, j As Long

    String1 = "Hello"
    String2 = "Goodbye"
    TestString = "Hello and Goodbye"
    i = InStr(1, TestString, String1, vbTextCompare)
    If i > 0 Then
        j = InStr(i + Len(String1), TestString, String2, vbTextCompare)
        If j > 0 Then
            'Do Something
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

`i` gives the position of `String1` and `j` gives the position of `String2` if these are required for your Do Something code

Note that the other answer here may give false results if `String2` is a substring of `String` or if `String2` occurs both before and after `String1`